# triangle package does not work on jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am new to jupyter notebook. I am trying to run my R codes on jupyter notebook so I can share them with my team. when I run my codes using triangle package. I get the this error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name): there is no package called 'triangle'
Traceback:

1. triangle::rltriangle
2. getExportedValue(pkg, name)
3. asNamespace(ns)
4. getNamespace(ns)
5. loadNamespace(name)
6. withRestarts(stop(cond), retry_loadNamespace = function() NULL)
7. withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
8. doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
```

I have added r-triangle package using Anaconda. but this didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Check your `.libPaths()` and within each of those directories, ensure you have a `triangle` directory. If not, then your installation using Anaconda was not successful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I re-installed triangle package then launched jupyter notebook. and it is working now.